# update-alternative command not found

Tags: command-line

I want to run the following:

```
sudo update-alternative --config java
```

However, the `update-alternative` command is not found.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `update-alternatives`.
So you should be running `sudo update-alternatives --config java`.